# Como traduzir Subject

Tags: tradução-inglês

Como traduzir Subject para o português formalmente? No contrato em inglês quando inserido Subject estão se referindo a "pessoa física /jurídica"?

Comment: Existem vários usos de "subject" no inglês jurídico. Inserido como? (Por favor, faça um esforço com os acentos e pontuação senão tudo vira "pé na jaca".)

Comment: Bem vinda ao site Amanda. Se possivel por favor edite a pergunta para incluir uma citação e link para um texto de referência, assim fica melhor para os leitores verem um exemplo concreto de utilização da palavra.

Answer (score -1):

A palavra `subject` tem alguns significados, e sua tradução dependerá do contexto. [Seus significados](https://www.wordreference.com/enpt/subject) incluem:

- *substantivo* assunto; tema
- *substantivo* matéria; disciplina (escolar)
- *substantivo* sujeito
- *verbo* submeter

Para saber como traduzí-lo em um contexto específico, forneça o contexto na pergunta.